# Need help understanding a merge and "Closed with unmerged commits" message

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand this process and, from a git functionality point of view as well as an open source development POV, what happened here.

[This PR gets](https://github.com/databricks/spark-pr-dashboard/pull/53#issuecomment-100317156) a thumbs up and LGTM comment, then ends as "Closed with unmerged commits." The commits I provided have been applied. The specific commit added [is here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-pr-dashboard/commit/af3600f1dd866ab2621dce55705b5f3ca7f01011) and is visualized in a way that I don't understand what it implies:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like that person does not merge PRs but instead uses "git merge pull/number master" and then pushes that to github. You can tell because there are no PR merge notes in the commit history. See here for an example of how you can checkout a PR from origin, which you can then merge/push back to origin: https://sethvargo.com/checkout-a-github-pull-request/

It keeps a cleaner history, which many people enjoy, but doesn't give "credit" to the authors publicly - though it does in the commit history. It's not exactly normal but it is an accepted workflow.